# GSSException: No valid credentials provided in bootstrapStandBy with Java 8

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I have configured HA Cluster hadoop-2.7.2 security with Kerberos in Windows. Its working fine on Jdk7 but fails on Jdk8 (Jdk1.8.0.131)

```
hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby
```

Formatting second namenode with above command fails [log details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSl8G.jpg)

```
7/05/12 10:59:00 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, status: 403, message: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:425)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
```